# Can i use this script in SharePoint online in a webpart - Trying a weather webpart

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to use the below script to show weather via sharepoint online.
But it doesn't work.
It works with sharepoint on premises.
Any ideas.Thanks in Advance

The webpart just goes blank showing only the background image:(

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://xxx.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/zWeatherFeed/jquery.zweatherfeed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://xxx.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/zWeatherFeed/example_jquerytools.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="scrollable vertical">
    <div id="test" class="items"></div>
</div>
<div class="navi"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">



$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').weatherfeed(['ASXX0112','ASXX0075','RPXX0017'],{},function(e) {
        $("div.scrollable").scrollable({ 
                vertical: true,  
                size: 1,
                        link: false,
            circular: true
        }).navigator().autoscroll({
            interval: 3000
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: does your script console (on the developer tools) display any error ?

Comment: Does your browser block mixed content? Trying using https for your first two scripts.

Answer (score 3):

I added your code to one of my pages, and changed the jQuery/jQuery Tools links to use https.  IE Dev tools threw an error about insecure content, and after looking in the `zweatherfeed.min.js` file, I saw that it was using http in a few links, so I changed them to https.  That gave me this:

[image]

And the following error in IE Dev tools:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'scrollable'
```

Make sure all your links use https, and fix your `.scrollable()` method, and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks guys for the input.I basically downloaded some script and added them to my site assests library.But as wjervis mentioned i cant see the images.Im not getting the scrollable error but no images.Thanks in Advance

Comment: All done and fix now.I had to edit the file and adjusted the file not to use https:as this did the trick
Any ideas how to make the weather images smaller